# emacs mark from point to start of buffer?

Tags: mark

I know one can mark the whole buffer with `mark-whole-buffer`.

but how does one mark from point (that line) to start of buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this:

- `C-SPC` to set the mark
- `M-<` to go to the beginning of the buffer

Or, if you want to finish with point where you started:

- `M-<` to go to the beginning of the buffer (which sets the mark at point but does not activate the mark)
- `C-x C-x` to activate the mark and swap mark and point.

If you do this a lot, you can define a command:

```
(defun mark-to-beginning-of-buffer ()
  "Marks the region from the beginning of the buffer to point."
  (interactive)
  (push-mark (point-min) nil t))
```

Comment: @Gilles Good point, thanks for the edit.